# Why my static React website is freezing in localhost?

Tags: reactjs, browser, static

I created a static React website, there is no database, no node.js, no login system. It is a simple company website with many SVG images and a lot of CSS work. I made it with Bootstrap 4. But when I try to run it on localhost it freezes many times. I am unable to figure out why the website is hanging, also it takes time to load all the SVG images.

 Can anyone tell why does it freezes?

Comment: I usually encounter freezes when using react when react get triggered to re-render infinitely, something like useEffect that updates state without a dependency array can cause this (more explanation [here](https://dmitripavlutin.com/react-useeffect-infinite-loop/)). 

But there are many things that can cause freezes, you'll need to show the code that freezes for anyone to help.